# Запись и чтения списка в текстовом файле

Tags: python, list, список, текстовые-файлы

я хочу список ['ТЕКСТ', 'ТЕКСТ 1\nТЕКСТ 2', ['текст 3', 'текст 4']] записать в текстовый файл и при чтении текстового файла получать такой же список

```
mas = ['ТЕКСТ', 'ТЕКСТ 1\nТЕКСТ 2', ['текст 3', 'текст 4']]

with open('C:\\Code\\ST3\\e minor code\\profile.txt', 'w') as f:     
    text = ''
    for i in range(len(mas)):
        if i == 0 or i == 1:
            text += '\n' + mas[i] + '\n'
        else:
            text += '\n' + '\n'.join(mas[i]) + '\n\n'

    f.write(text)

with open('C:\\Code\\ST3\\e minor code\\profile.txt', 'r') as f:
    mas_in = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    mas_out = []
    mas_end = [i for i in range(len(mas_in)) if mas_in[i] == '' or i == 0 or i + 1 == len(mas_in)]
    
    for i in range(len(mas_end) - 1):
        mas = [mas_in[j] for j in range(mas_end[i] + 1, mas_end[i + 1])]
        if i == 0:
            mas_out.append(mas[0])
        elif i == 1:
            mas_out.append('\n'.join(mas))
        else:
            mas_out.append(mas)

    mas_in = mas_out
```

Есть ли более рациональный способ решения данной задачи ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве одного из вариантов - сохранять как json.

```
import json

mas = ['ТЕКСТ', 'ТЕКСТ 1\nТЕКСТ 2', ['текст 3', 'текст 4']]

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(mas, f, ensure_ascii=False)

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    new_mas = json.load(f)

print(new_mas)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если цель состоит в том, чтобы сохранить объект в файл, а потом восстановить его из файла. То для этого есть модуль [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Он предназначен для сериализации и десериализации структуры объектов. С его помощью можно также сохранять классы, включая вложенность (в отличии от json). Правда данные сохраняются в бинарном формате, а не текстовом (в отличии от json).

Если формат файла не принципиален, то можно сделать так:

```
import pickle

mas = ['ТЕКСТ', 'ТЕКСТ 1\nТЕКСТ 2', ['текст 3', 'текст 4']]
with open('filename.bin', 'w+b') as f:
    pickle.dump(mas, f)  

with open('filename.bin', 'r+b') as f:
    mas2 = pickle.load(f)  
    
print(mas2)
# ['ТЕКСТ', 'ТЕКСТ 1\nТЕКСТ 2', ['текст 3', 'текст 4']]
```